# Move a Character in a 2d Array

Tags: c++

I'm taking an intro to c++ class and I am quite stuck on a part to this project.

I need to have my character, 'H' move freely around the array. I have written a good amount of my code, but when I compile and run it, my hero isn't given the option to move. I don't know what is going wrong when I am calling my function in main. Any help would be gladly appreciated. I need his new position in the array to be maintained so that he can find the villain who is randomly placed in the array. I can work on the randint part later, but I am having a hard time simply getting 'H' to move.
Here is what I have so far:
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printBoard(char board[][8])
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
            cout << board[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void move(char board[][8], char umove)
{
    cout << "Please enter which direction you would like to move." << endl;
    cin >> umove;

    if (umove == 'x')
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                board[x][y] = x - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (umove == 'd')
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                board[x][y] = y + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (umove == 'a')
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                board[x][y] = y - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (umove == 'w')
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                board[x][y] = x + 1;
            }
        }
    }

}

char userinput()
{
    char usermove;
    cout << "Please enter the direction you want to go." << endl;

    cin >> usermove;

    return usermove;
}

int main()
{
    char board[8][8];
    int x;
    int y;
    while (true)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                board[x][y] = 'e';
            }
        }

        board[0][0] = 'H';

        printBoard(board);
        void move();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: ` void move();` is a method declaration in your code which do nothing. `return 0` finish program while the `while` loop execute only once. you has a board of `char` but you assign it a integer in method `move`. I can't understand this. Is it possible to edit and add more detail? What do you want to do?

Comment: When I run the program, I would like H to move around the board when I press w, a, x or d in the corresponding directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you call `void move()` which is a method declaration and you must use `move(...)` instead for calling method. `return 0` cause the app to finish which is not correct in this situation. you use infinite loop and you must use a condition for finish game.
depend on your description I suggest:

```
void printBoard(char board[][8]) {
    // same as before
}

bool move(char board[][8], int &Hx, int &Hy) {
    char umove;
    cout << "Please enter which direction you would like to move." << endl;
    cin >> umove;
    if (umove == 'f') // f mean finish it
        return false;

    board[Hx][Hy] = 'e';
    if (umove == 'a') // a mean left
        Hy = Hy == 0 ? 7 : Hy - 1;
    else if (umove == 'd') // d mean right
        Hy = Hy == 7 ? 0 : Hy + 1;
    else if (umove == 'w') // w mean up
        Hx = Hx == 0 ? 7 : Hx - 1;
    else if (umove == 's')  // s mean down
        Hx = Hx == 7 ? 0 : Hx + 1;
    board[Hx][Hy] = 'H';
    return true;
}

int main() {
    char board[8][8];
    int Hx = 0, Hy = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            board[x][y] = 'e';
        }
    }
    board[Hx][Hy] = 'H';
    bool res = true;
    while (res) {
        printBoard(board);
        res = move(board, Hx, Hy);
    }
    cout << "Game finished!";
    return 0;
}
```

You can make `char board[][]` and `Hx` and `Hy` (which contain current position of H) global and avoid sending them to method but this is not good at all.
I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, this helped out.  I was trying to get H to move across the board by using another void function, but using the bool seems like the best method to do so.

Comment: Your welcome. if you can accept or vote up for others to know that is true.